# margin-left 5px in bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have 2 buttons, I would like to put a spacing between the 2 buttons.

In CSS I will do `margin-left: 5px`

On bootstrap I don't find the class exact ?

```html
    div class="d-flex">
         <button (click)="showPreviousYear()" *ngIf="showPreviousYearButton()" class="btn btn-primary">
             &lt; {{previousYear}}
         </button>
         <button (click)="showNextYear()" *ngIf="showNextYearButton()" class="btn btn-primary ">
            {{nextYear}} &gt;
         </button>
    </div>
```

For now, I added a class `myClass` in CSS

```html
    ...
    <button (click)="showNextYear()" *ngIf="showNextYearButton()" class="btn btn-primary myClass ">
    ...
```

En CSS

```css
    .myClass  {
        margin-left: 5px;
    }
```

If you have another solution in bootstrap, I am interested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have read at the documentation
[bootstrap-spacing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/)

**tl;dr**

Classes used for left margin are ml-{n}.
This does not set margin to 5px but uses percentage

```
<div ml-5> </div>
```

Comment: Thank you it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

**bootstrap 5 update his utilities.**

ms means margin start applying to margin-left

**class="ms-5"**

me means margin end applying to margin-right

class="me-5"